# I can't submit with jConfirm

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I want to use the plugin jConfirm to confirm the submit of a form.

He is the code :

```
<form name="FLigne" id="FLigne" target="_self" method="post" action="Listeligne">
.....
<p><input type="submit" id="bSupprimer" name="Valide" value="Supprimer la ligne" class="boutons" onclick="return confirmSubmit();"></p>
</form>

<script>
function confirmSubmit() {
jConfirm("Confirmez-vous la suppression de la ligne ?", "confirmation", function(r) { return r });
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the jConfirm dialog doesn't suspend the submit event.
The result is a quick view to the dialog and the submit event append without confirm.

note : the standard "confirm" suspend the event (because it is modal ; jConfirm isn't) but it isn't very beautiful.

I try to prevent the submit event (with preventDefaut()), show the jConfirm dialog and submit the form with `$("#FLigne").submit();` => The submit is bad and the servlet called does not retrieve the values of the form... :'(

What can I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have jquery you can use submit handler. you dont need to use inline javascript.

**Script Code:**

```
$('form#FLigne').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   jConfirm("Confirmez-vous la suppression de la ligne ?", "confirmation", function(result){
      if(result)  $('input#bSupprimer').click();
   });
});
```

**HTML:** remove the onclick call

```
<form name="FLigne" id="FLigne" target="_self" method="post" action="Listeligne">
.....
<p><input type="submit" id="bSupprimer" name="Valide" value="Supprimer la ligne" class="boutons"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: I try : The jconfirm dialog does the work but the submit is bad. In the servlet, the "request.getParameter" for the submit buttons returns "null" instead of the value of the button....
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: got your problem.. try it now.. i am sure your pbm will be resolved... instead submiting the form, need to click submit button.

Comment: i changed $('input#bSupprimer').click(); inside if condition... earlier i was submiting form by $('form').submit() but now submiting the fomr by clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<input type="submit" id="bSupprimer" name="Valide" value="Supprimer la ligne" class="boutons" onclick="return confirmSubmit();">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="bSupprimer" name="Valide" value="Supprimer la ligne" class="boutons" onclick="return confirmSubmit();">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ^_^
I tried : no submit append.
I tried to submit with type "button" : the submit is bad.

Comment: The problem was resolved : input type submit, no token "onclick" and a submit function that contains a click forced with jquery upon the button.
Thank you for your help !